# PSBT (BIP-174, Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction) Ordering of keys

Tags: bip174-psbt

When serializing a [PSBT](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki) (BIP-174, Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction), I cannot find any information if the keys should be ordered when serializing the PSBT?

Under the "Test Vectors" section for the BIP-174 in the last example it is only mentioned that:

> A combiner which orders keys *lexicographically* must produce the
>   following PSBT[...]

But it does nowhere say that it is mandatory to order the keys. What is expected?

I am implementing test cases for a PSBT library and would like to know this to decide if I should compare the serialized PSBTs (where ordering does matter) or the objects themselves (regardless of ordering of keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mandatory ordering. If you assume your parser is correct, then it is fine to compare the objects themselves. However, to be sure everything is correct, I would suggest that you compare the serialized PSBTs themselves.